# Can I implement Google maps or another mapping API on my site?

Tags: google-maps, licensing, mapping

> 9.1 Free, Public Accessibility to Your Maps API Implementation. Your Maps API
>   Implementation must be generally
>   accessible to users without charge.
>   You may require users to log in to
>   your Maps API Implementation if you do
>   not require users to pay a fee.not require users to pay a fee.

I write a web portal and sell it. The company that bought it then offers access to it for free to a select group of people. I want to incorporate one small feature using the maps API to let them put points on a map and share those points with other people.

I suspect it violates those terms, but I am not sure. If it does, can anyone think of a suitable solution? Can I put the mapping part on a public bit of the site? I could host the tool separately, for example, and make it accessible to everyone. Is there an alternate free API I could use?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing / terms of use / legal issues, not programming or software development. See the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wondered that myself with a recent project, but I suspect it is OK. It says that it is OK to require users to log in, provided they are not required to pay a fee.

That is, the users of the web site are not required to pay a fee. The fact that you sold the portal to someone else is not relevant at all; it's the end-users that matter for that. If they are 'required to pay a fee', it isn't appropriate. It seems also that the word 'required' would allow its use on a site that offered 'freemium' access, too.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense, I just wonder if say, a company uses it to keep track of its employees. The employees don't pay, but it's not public either.

Answer (score 2):

You really want a lawyer to review your implementation if you are unsure whether it violates the TOS or not.  That said, google does offer a "premiere" service that allows you to implement it on private sites.  You may want to look into using this (the cost scales with number of requests.)

Comment: Both very excellent points, Mike. Especially due to the appearance that the TOS does not seem to cover the use being asked about here.